# How to write case sensitive queries in kql

Tags: azure, kql, kqlmagic

I am writing the below code in KQL :-

```
 UserBaseTable
| where RawData contains_cs "REF "
```

I want the records which start with the string REF but when I run the above command I get records where in the "REF" string is coming in between also. I tried using the contains_cs also but it only works with the case sentivity not with the position of the searchable string. How do I get the desired result

Also the or operator doesnt work for me in KQL. Do we have a different usage of the "OR" operator?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [startswith_cs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/startswith-cs-operator) it could do what you're needing.

```
let T = datatable (R:string) [
'reformed',
'reformat',
'refreeze',
'refrains',
'refilled',
'reFramed',
'rEFrozen',
'REFlected',
'REFLECTS',
'REF erence'
];
T
| where R startswith_cs 'REF'
```

Wordlist courtesy of [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-that-start-with-ref).

My output:
|R|
|-|
|REFlected|
|REFLECTS|
|REF erence|

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **startswith_cs** operator in KQL to get the records that start with the string "REF". Here is the code:

```
UserBaseTable
| where startswith(RawData, "REF")
```

This will return only the records where the "REF" string is at the beginning of the RawData field.

[demo](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAysuSSwqKS7PLMmITy4GAA+suNcNAAAA)

**Reference**: [The case-sensitive startswith string operator - Azure Data Explorer - Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/startswith-cs-operator)